# XML Parsing problems getting #text in nodeList

Tags: java, xml

I'm writing an XML parser to parse documents like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<world x="1920" y="1080">
    <samples>2</samples>
    <camera>
        <origin x="0.0" y="50.0" z="-600.0"></origin>
        <direction x= "0.0" y = "0.0" z = "0.0"></direction>
        <FOV>30</FOV>
    </camera>
    <objects>
        <plane>
            <shader>Lambertian</shader>
            <colour r="1.0" g="1.0" b="1.0"></colour>
            <origin x="0.0" y="-80.0" z="0.0"></origin>
            <normal x="0.0" y="-1.0" z="0.0"></normal>
        </plane>
        <sphere>
            <shader>Lambertian</shader>
            <colour r="0.0" g="1.0" b="0.0"></colour>
            <origin x="-100.0" y="-40.0" z="-200.0"></origin>
            <radius>40</radius>
        </sphere>
        <sphere>
            <shader>Reflective</shader>
            <origin x="0.0" y="-40.0" z="-200.0"></origin>
            <radius>40</radius>
        </sphere>
        <sphere>
            <shader>Transparent</shader>
            <origin x="-40.0" y="-40.0" z="-300.0"></origin>
            <radius>40</radius>
            <ri>1.07</ri>
        </sphere>
    </objects>
    <lights>
        <light>
            <origin x="100.0" y="200.0" z="-300.0"></origin>
            <colour r="1.0" g="1.0" b="1.0"></colour>
        </light>
        <light>
            <origin x="-100.0" y="300.0" z="-400.0"></origin>
            <colour r="0.5" g="0.5" b="0.5">origin</colour>
        </light>
    </lights>
</world>
```

However I'm having some trouble my code for parsing so far is:

```java
File inputFile = new File(fileName);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);

doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

Element rootEle = doc.getDocumentElement();

String resX = rootEle.getAttribute("x");
String resY = rootEle.getAttribute("y");

int width = Integer.parseInt(resX);
int height = Integer.parseInt(resY);

RayTracer.setWorld(width, height);

NodeList nodes = rootEle.getChildNodes();

System.out.println(nodes.item(0).getNodeName());

Node sampler = nodes.item(1);

String samplesTemp = sampler.getTextContent();

System.out.println(samplesTemp);

int samples = Integer.parseInt(samplesTemp);

RayTracer.setSampler(samples);

Node camera = nodes.item(2);
```

but I'm getting weird results, for instance in `System.out.println(nodes.item(0).getNodeName());` I got #text and I'm not sure where that comes from. For `item(1)` I get samples, `item(2)` I get #text and `item(3)` I get camera.

Comment: The docs are pretty helpful https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getNodeName(), also what exactly is your question?

Comment: I'm relieved to see that you are NOT writing an XML parser: you are writing an application that makes calls on an XML parser.

Comment: As I remember, I solved this with `instance of Text` and skipped the Node.

Answer (score 0):

If your xml is exactly formatted like in your example, e.g.

```
<world x="1920" y="1080">
    <samples>2</samples>
    ....
</world>
```

Then there is `#text` between the start tag `<world>` and the start tag `samples`. In this case there is a line break and four whitespaces. This are together the first node after `<world>`.

Perhaps you want to [ignore the whitespaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(boolean)).